# AIR-How to upgrade the version of apk for android

Tags: android, air, adobe

I'm using adobe air to provide video call. It's been developed using flash builder. I have the source code.

The problem is when I compile it using flash builder it gives me the apk that doesn't work on android 4.4 or upper. There is a runtime.apk file in adobe flash.

My question is: can I get an apk that works in android 4.4 if I update that runtime.apk file or what can I do to make apk work in android 4.4 or up?

Answer (score 1):

To support newer versions of Android you must compile your application with the latest AIR SDK.

If you are a Flex developer I recommend to use the Apache Flex Installer:
https://flex.apache.org/installer.html

It will create a ready to use SDK with the latest versions of AIR and Flex SDKS so you can use it on Flash Builder.

If your app is made in pure ActionScript 3 then you only need to download the AIR SDK from here:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html

And then follow this instructions:
https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/kb/overlay-air-sdk-flash-builder.html

Which basically is to download, unzip and replace the old AIR SDK in the Flash Builder plugins folder with the most recent one.

Don't forget to change the AIR version in your descriptor file, from 3.1 to 23./24.0, it is in the second line.